# Node.js' public/private key pair not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rsa

I'm using a library called "[jsencrypt](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt)" for RSA encryption in a project of mine, while generating key pairs using nodejs' default crypto library. My code is as follows:

```
importScripts("./jsencrypt.js")
function encryption() {

          const { generateKeyPairSync } = require('crypto');
          const { pubkey, privkey } = generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
            modulusLength: 4096,  
            publicKeyEncoding: {
              type: 'spki',       
              format: 'pem'
            },
            privateKeyEncoding: {
              type: 'pkcs8',      
              format: 'pem',
              cipher: 'aes-256-cbc',   
              passphrase: 'top secret' 
            }
          });

          var encrypt = new JSEncrypt();
          encrypt.setPublicKey(pubkey);
          var encrypted = encrypt.encrypt("test");

          var decrypt = new JSEncrypt();
          decrypt.setPrivateKey(privkey);
          var uncrypted = decrypt.decrypt(encrypted);

          if (uncrypted == "test") {
            self.postMessage('works');
          }
          else {
            self.postMessage('error');
          }
        }



self.onmessage = function(e) {
    encryption()
  };
```

(This is running on a webworker, since I'm using NW.js for the project which supports webworkers with node.js modules on it)

For some reason this is returning "error" (and nothing shows on the devtools). Running this same function but removing the key generation and using the key pair sample given on jsencrypt's github works fine though.

Anyone can help me find why?

Comment: Okay, so `uncrypted != "test"`. Have you tried logging what it actually is? `console.log(uncrypted)`

Comment: it simply logs false

Comment: [`crypto.generateKeyPairSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_generatekeypairsync_type_options) says it returns an object with `publicKey` and `privateKey` properties, not `pubkey` and `privkey`. Are those `undefined`?

Comment: Oh I haven't noticed that. I thought I could change those two on that first constant but seems I can't. Changing back it now is making keys correctly but the function was still not working as it should. Removing the lines ",
              cipher: 'aes-256-cbc',   
              passphrase: 'top secret' " made everything work